# Unable to open debugger port in IntelliJ

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

Unable to open debugger port in intellij.
The port number 9009 matches the one which has been set in the configuration file for the application.

```
<java-config debug-options="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9009" system-classpath="" native-library-path-prefix="D:\Project\lib\windows\64bit" classpath-suffix="">
    <jvm-options>-XX:MaxPermSize=192m</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-client</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-XX:+LogVMOutput</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-XX:LogFile=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/logs/jvm.log</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-Djava.endorsed.dirs=${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/modules/endorsed${path.separator}${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/lib/endorsed</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-Djava.security.policy=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/server.policy</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-Djava.security.auth.login.config=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/login.conf</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/keystore.jks</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/cacerts.jks</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-Djava.ext.dirs=${com.sun.aas.javaRoot}/lib/ext${path.separator}${com.sun.aas.javaRoot}/jre/lib/ext${path.separator}${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/lib/ext</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=4766</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/modules/autostart/</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-Dfelix.fileinstall.debug=1</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-Dorg.glassfish.web.rfc2109_cookie_names_enforced=false</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-XX:NewRatio=2</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-Xmx2048m</jvm-options>
  </java-config>
```

Configuration in IntelliJ:

[image]

When I try and enable the remote debugging in for this application it comes up with the following error:
[image]

Comment: The port does not seem to be open. What does your applications log file say? Normally it would say something like this: `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9009`.

Comment: @maba : The port was open as I had run telnet 192.168.2.100 9009 .However netstat was not working so that meant there was a problem in the glassfish configuration.So I  added the following configuration parameter in the java-config in glassfish in my answer below and it worked.Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: make sure you are using correct `run configuration`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the following parameter debug-enabled="true" to this line in the glassfish configuration.
Example:

```
<java-config  debug-options="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9009" debug-enabled="true"
  system-classpath="" native-library-path-prefix="D:\Project\lib\windows\64bit" classpath-suffix="">
```

Start and stop the glassfish domain or service which was using this configuration.

Comment: What if you're not using glassfish?

Answer (score 48):

You may have to change the debugger port if your port is already used by another program. To do so:

- Run
- Edit Configurations
- Startup/Connection tab
- Debug
- Change the port here

---

Or, maybe in other versions:

- Run
- Edit Configurations
- Remote > Remote debug in the list on the left
- Configuration tab, Settings section
- Port: change the port here

Comment: What if you're not using the default configuration, and instead made a custom remote configuration?

Comment: You mean using remote debugger on localhost:8000 ? If so you need to specify debugging options in the JVM of your application (Run), but the problem is the same, you need a free port.

Comment: @Pleymor I’m not seeing any “Startup/Connection” tab from Run > Edit Configurations in my Android Studio 2.2.2 on Mac OSX. Has this changed?

Comment: @MrColes I guess it works only for `IntelliJ IDEA` and not `Android Studio`

Comment: Worked with eclipse for me. I encountered the issue after putting Idea at 5005 but for some reason i wasn't even able to use Idea again to do a run. Changed the config to 5006 and then it worked.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and this solution also did the trick for me: Provide the IP 127.0.0.1 in the Intellij Debug configuration instead of the host name "localhost", in case you're using this hostname.

Comment: This solved it for me as well after hours of banging my head on the wall, this is absurd. Why is this not mentioned in any of the documentation??? As far as I'm concerned, assuming all the other directions were followed correctly, this is the #1 real issue with remote debugging with IntelliJ, it just can't grok localhost properly.

Comment: If you are working behind the VPN and entering 127.0.0.1 does not solve the issue, try also with IP assigned to you by VPN provider (worked in my case)

Answer (score 8):

You must set CHMOD +x (execute for *.sh or *.bat files). For example, I am using macOS

```
cd /Users/donhuvy/Documents/tools/apache-tomcat-9.0.12/bin
sudo chmod +x *.sh
```

Then IntelliJ IDEA, and Apache Tomcat running or debugging just good.

Comment: This was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

1. In `glassfish\domains\domain1\config\domain.xml` set before start server

```xml
<java-config classpath-suffix="" debug-options="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=9009,server=y,suspend=n" java-home="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162" debug-enabled="true" system-classpath="">
```

or set debug-enabled="true" server=y,suspend=n in http://localhost:4848/common/index.jsf
[image: Glassfish 4 address=9009,server=y,suspend=n]

2. In current Idea 2018 - Server Run Configuration - Debug - Port - address
   [image: Server Run Configuration - Debug - Port - address]

Answer (score 3):

I'm hoping your problem has been solved by now.  If not, try this...  It looks like you have `server=y` for both your app and IDEA.  IDEA should probably be `server=n`.  Also, the (IDEA) client should have an address that includes both the host name and the port, e.g., `address=127.0.0.1:9009`.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me--
If the issue still persists (in case you are not using a glassFish server), then close your JIdea and stop the server. This will disable the ports connectivity. Then start your server and JIdea, this will start fresh connectivity with the ports, resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was that catalina.sh didnt have execute permissions. The "Unable to open debugger port in intellij" message appeared in Intellij, but it sort of masked the 'could not execute catalina.sh' error that appeared in the logs immediately prior.

Answer (score 1):

This error can happen Tomcat is already running.  So make sure Tomcat isn't running in the background if you've asked Intellij to start it up ( default ).

Also, check the full output window for more errors.  As a more useful error may have preceded this one ( as was the case with my configuration just now )

Answer (score 0):

Answer is pretty simple,
I also faced the problem finally I got perfect solution.
[Create Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJv7P.jpg)
[Create Remote debug with following configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQBjj.jpg)
Firstly run by debug.
It gives you waitng for socket 5005
then run with remote debug

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect with telnet  , if it connects then it shows below:

$telnet 10.238.136.165 9999
Trying 10.238.136.165...
Connected to 10.238.136.165.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

If port is not available (either because someone else is already connected to it or the port is not open etc) then it shows something like it shows like below:

$telnet 10.238.136.165 9999
Trying 10.238.136.165...
telnet: connect to address 10.238.136.165: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

So I think one needs to see whether:

- the application is property listening to port or not
- or someone else has already connected to it

Also try to connect on that m/c itself first like 
$telnet localhost 9999

Answer (score 0):

Run your Spring Boot application with the given command to enable debugging on port 6006 while the server is up on port 8090:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments='-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=6006' -Dserver.port=8090
```

Answer (score 0):

**Set the MAVEN_OPTS. It should work !!**

export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=n"

mvn spring-boot:run  -Dserver.port=8090

Answer (score 0):

Your Service/ Application might already be running. In Search enter Services and you will get list of services. Stop yours and then try again.

Comment: This can be a comment and not an answer. Please, check the rules of this community.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I just have to remove the HTTP protocol from the URL. That's it.

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I once have this problem too.
My solution is to work around this problem by kill the application which is using the port.
[Here](https://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/10/how-to-check-which-application-is-using-which-port/) is a article to teach us how to check which application is using which port, find it and kill/close it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was not setting the debug port while starting the application.
I am using tomcat to deploy 3 war files, and I forgot to configure the debug port.

Tomcat allows us to configure this via `setenv.sh`.

Here are the commands to create `setenv.sh` file in the bin directory of my tomcat installation and provide the debug arguments/port.

```
tee /usr/share/tomcat9/bin/setenv.sh << EOF
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
EOF

service tomcat9 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I change the port from 6xxxxx to 2xxxxx and it works now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old thread but I am using tomcat with spring boot and none of above worked for me. As of Oct, 2023, Intellij Community Edition suggests following command line arguments for JVM

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005
```

[image]

However, when I run my application with following command:

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005 -jar myApp.jar --spring.profiles.active=local
```

I didn't get the following line

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

With help of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43800535/3369001, I changed it to

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -jar myApp.jar --spring.profiles.active=local
```

Instead of `address=*:5005`, use `address=5005`.

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the debugger port works for me. [screenshot of tomcat config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFuk1.jpg)

Comment: Hello, please don't post image/code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used. Screenshots are especially bad.

Answer (score -1):

Merely hitting the debug icon again fixed my problem in a few seconds.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to specify an SDK and Project SDK for your app under File --> Project Structure (Project | SDKs)