# Debugger Configuration in Intellij with Gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I am using Intellij IDEA 13.0 along with gradle to manage my build. I've created a debugger via Run > Edit Configurations... then added a new Remote.

I've left the preset values as they are.

When I run the debugger I get:

```
 Error running Debugger: Unable to open debugger port : java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused"
```

Do I need to set something to listen on that port?

This is my first time using this IDE and my first java project in a few years so this is pretty unfamiliar.

Comment: What do you wish to debug?

Comment: have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792833/unable-to-open-debugger-port-in-intellij

Comment: Hi yeah I've seen that question, not sure on where I would set the values as in that question they use glassfish. I want to debug some tests.

Comment: Then just right click on the test folder and select "debug". No need to launch a remote debugger for that, IDEA will do that for you

Comment: Ah wow, I was overcomplicating the matter a lot by relying on the gradle command to run my tests. So @fge yes that worked as I wanted it to. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you tell intellij to use a remote debug configuration, it will try and connect to a Java process that's been started with the remote debugging parameters, e.g. "-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000".

Comment: Ah ok so I'm running my tests using the gradle wrapper, does that mean  I need to supply the values above to the command I run the tests with? So at the moment I'm running ./gradlew test.

Comment: I've not tried it, just having a tablet to hand,but I suspect that you could do it by setting them in GRADLE_OPTS in yourenvironment, then running gradle as normal.

Comment: So when I export those vars, after running `gradle test` I get `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005` in the console. Still doesn't break in the code though.

Comment: Do you get the "Connected" message in Intellij? You need to runup the app, then start the debug session in Intellij, and it should print something to that effect in the debug console, then breakpoints, etc, should be working as expected.

Comment: Yeah I think all this is just complicating matters as I only really want to put a breakpoint in a test so probably @fge answer is fine. The situation you're describing where I run the app that then hits a breakpoint isn't one in which I'm in at the moment. Thanks for your comments.