# IntelliJ throwing Java.Net.SocketException: unable to open debugger, "socket closed"

Tags: java, web-services, debugging, intellij-idea, websphere

I have seen several topics on this problem, but all of them are either for Android Studio or Glassfish.

**Problem:**

I'm sending a POST Request from Postman to a web app hosted in WebSphere. I set a breakpoint in the web service code in IntelliJ, but when I fire up the debugger, I get this error:

```
Error running 'WebSphere Traditional 8.5.5.0': Unable to open debugger port 
(127.x.x.x:xxxxx): java.net.SocketException "socket closed"
```

**WebSphere Debug Configuration in IntelliJ:**
[image]

**Things I've tried:**

- read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792833/unable-to-open-debugger-port-in-intellij) and discovered the WebSphere debug configuration
- restart the app server
- restart the web service
- restart IntelliJ
- restart my PC
- read several Android Studio posts on the same subject
- read the JavaDoc on Java.net.SocketException
- blasphemed

**Questions:**

- If the issue is simply that I need to change the debug port, how can I determine what to change it to?
- If necessary, where in the WebSphere Application Server admin console would I navigate to if I wanted to check the sockets? I'm very new to WebSphere AS and the documentation is a bit scattered.

Comment: Try to disable antivirus/firewall or use any other free port.

Comment: Our IT department has advised me not to change ports, and they control the firewall. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Since the connection is on `localhost`, there is no danger in allowing it on your firewall. You can use any free port.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was human error.

Because of my poor understanding of WebSphere, I was starting the server manually, and then starting the web service in IntelliJ.

IntelliJ was trying to launch the server for me, but when it saw that the server was already running, it threw an error stating that the socket was closed.

**The solution** was simply to let IntelliJ to launch the server as part of the Run process.